# Remix Run UploadHandler Using Data for WhatsApp API Media Upload

Tags: node.js, facebook, whatsapp, remix.run

I am attempting to use a form in Remix to add a file and then upload that file to WhatsApp using their Cloud API Media Upload endpoint. Below is my initial code within the `action`. The current error I am receiving is `message: '(#100) The parameter messaging_product is required.`. I feel like this error may be misleading based off the form data I have appended with the "messaging_product".

```
export async function action({ request, params }: ActionArgs) {
  const uploadHandler = unstable_composeUploadHandlers(
    async ({ name, contentType, data, filename }) => {
      const whatsAppPhoneId = process.env.WHATSAPP_PHONE_ID;
      const whatsAppToken = process.env.WHATSAPP_ACCESS_TOKEN;

      const dataArray1 = [];

      for await (const x of data) {
        dataArray1.push(x);
      }

      const file1 = new File(dataArray1, filename, { type: contentType });
      const graphApiUrl = `https://graph.facebook.com/v15.0/${whatsAppPhoneId}/media`;
      const formData = new FormData();

      formData.append("file", file1);
      formData.append("messaging_product", "whatsapp");
      formData.append("type", contentType);

      try {
        const imageMediaResponse = await fetch(graphApiUrl, {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${whatsAppToken}`,
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
          },
          body: formData,
        });

        const imageMedia = await imageMediaResponse.json();

        return imageMedia?.id;
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }

      const whatsAppMediaId = await uploadWhatsAppImageMedia(
        whatsAppPhoneId,
        whatsAppToken,
        data,
        filename,
        contentType
      );
    }
  );

  const formData = await unstable_parseMultipartFormData(
    request,
    uploadHandler
  );
}
```